# How to dynamically load angular-locale by URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make use of `angular-locale`. But the locale parameter should be derived from the `GET` query and dynamically loaded on the launch of the webpage (I do not want to switch the user's locale lateron).

Problem: when I load the js lib dynamically, it seems to be too late and it falls back to `en-us`.

```
<!-- initialize the locale dynamically by request param -->
        <script>
            loadLocale();
        </script>

function loadLocale() {
    var lang = window.location.hash.split('?')... //find "lang" param and use this value

    var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = '//code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/i18n/angular-locale_" + lang + ".js"
        document.body.appendChild(s);
};
```

Using with:

`http://...?lang=de-de`

Question: so this is not working. But could I then initialize the app with a locale derived from a url paramter?

Comment: Try adding that function in setTimeout(loadLocale() , 10000);

Comment: COuld you give a morde detailed example?

Comment: Does this method delay the locale function execution by 10 seconds? If so, no that is not desired. I want to set the locale **before** anything of the anguljar app is rendered!